# Script to show javascript time on server not working

Tags: javascript, time

I am trying to show a live javascript clock on my page which shows the time on the server. I found this snippet of code on the internet a few weeks back however it doesn't seem to be doing what it claimed to do. It is showing the client time, not the server time. Any idea why?

```
flag = true;
timer = '';
setInterval(function(){phpJavascriptClock(<?php echo time(); ?>);},1000);


function phpJavascriptClock(timestamp)
{                 
  if ( flag ) {            
    timer = timestamp *  1000;
  }                     
  var d = new Date(timer);
  var currentDate = d.getDate();
  currentDate = currentDate < 10 ? '0'+currentDate : currentDate;

  var hours = d.getHours();    
  var minutes = d.getMinutes();
  var seconds = d.getSeconds();

  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour ’0' should be ’12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0'+seconds : seconds;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;

  var output = '';
  output += 
    '<a>'
    + '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-clock-o"></i>'
    + '<span class="">' + strTime + ' (SA)</span>'
    + '</a>'
  ;

  document.getElementById("current_time").innerHTML = output ;
  flag = false;
  timer = timer + 1000;
}
```

Comment: As you mentioned, this is looking at the browser's (user's machine) time. It doesn't make an AJAX call or something to connect to the server.

Comment: Can you verify that <?php echo time(); ?> prints a timestamp into your javascript function?

Comment: @asgs the server time is inserted into the function on line 3, should work fine because of that..

Comment: @asgs.. The servers timestamp is passed and I can confirm that this timestamp is correct so it's something on the js side that's not right.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at those lines above the function `phpJavascriptClock()`.

Comment: It's a fairly crappy script.. I might just wrote an Ajax one that directly gets the time from the server. I did find a jquery plugin that supposedly does what I want.. However I had the same problem with that one too.

Answer (score 0):

I see these 4 constructors for a Javascript `DATE`:

```
new Date()
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Could it be your timestamp is not `milliseconds` or `dateString` so Javascript just creates a new `Date()` object without any parameters (which is then the client time)?

Comment: Certainly a good point however I believe it is being passed in as milliseconds (timer *1000)

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a new jQuery based clock. Although it polls the server every minute, it works.

My controller that passes the time:

```
  public function getServerTimeAction() {
    global $config;
    try{
      $return["time"] = date("H:i a");
      $return["timezone"] = $config->application->timezone;

      $this->returnJson( JsonReturnObject::success( $return ) ) ;
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
      $this->returnJson( JsonReturnObject::error( $e ) ); 
    }    
  }
```

The jquery code:

```
function getServerTime() {
  $.ajax({
    url : "{{ url('json/session/get-server-time') }}",
    cache : false,
    success : function ( data ) {
      if ( data.success ) {                             
        var output = '';
        output += 
          '<a>'
          + '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-clock-o"></i>'
          + '<span class="">' + data.data.time + ' (SA)</span>'
          + '</a>'
        ;
        $("#current_time").html(output);
        setTimeout(getServerTime, 60000);                         
      }                
    }
  })
}
```